# An unhandled exception (' System.BadImageFormatException') occured in [15896] ReportWifiNetworkData.exe

Tags: runtime-error

I get this error randomly, without doing anything (I could watch a movie and it just pops up).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lH68.jpg

Also, when this error happens, I get ReportWifiNetworkData process in task manager, but when I close the error, it disappears.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I also have this same problem, it annoys me every time... 
Waiting for a solution too, if you find, please, post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing on my system. Looking at the task manager, I see it is started using a series of scripts:[image]

[image]

I tried modifying the RunScript.vbs, or the ReportWifinetworkdata.exe executable, but it just respawns in a new random-named folder under c:\windows\automation.
Sure looks suspicious...